# Prevent email spoofing?

Tags: email-spam

Is there anyway to stop email spoofing if someone or some bot is sending out emails with my domain name in the from address that do not originate from my server? People have forwarded emails to me stating they received spam from an email address from my domain yet the from email account does not exist on my server nor does it show it originated from my server via the headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no.

Mail sent through an open SMTP relay can appear as being from any e-mail address.

Answer (score 3):

You can use things like DKIM or SPF in your domain.  It means you are stating that you 'authorize' mail via server X.  These measures increase the 'reputation' of sending mail servers for your domain.

But the verification checks are made on the recipient.  No one really blocks based on SPF or DKIM since email is 'open' in that sense that you can send a 'valid' email from anywhere.

It's up to to the receiving email server to determine if they want to accept and forward on a sending email.